# What is wrong with my JQuery Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, visible

I want to make the #test element display:block; after clicking on the #button element.
And if I click again I want the #test element to be display:none;.

```
<body>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <!-- header -->
        <header id="top">
            <!--- Nav-bar -->
            <div id="button">   
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="test">
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#test').css("display","block")) {
            $('#test').css("display","none");
        } else {
            $('#test').css("display","block"); 
        }
    });            
});
```

I have no idea why it won't work!

Answer (score 3):

`.toggle()` is okay - but using css classes will give you better control ( say using CSS transitions in the future ) ( stops inline styling, but does the same job )

**CSS**

```
#test { display:none; }
#text.on { display:block; }
```

**JS/JQUERY**

```
  $('#button').on('click', function () {
     $('#test').toggleClass('on');
  });
```

Comment: for this ( if you need to check ) - `if( $('#test').hasClass('on')) { ..`

Answer (score 1):

Use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements.

```
 $(function () {
     $('#button').on('click', function () {
         $('#test').toggle();
     });
 });
```

---

```
if ($('#test').css("display","block")) {
```

you are setting `display`to  `block` instead of checking so it always be true.

---

if condition should be [FYI]

```
if ($('#test').css("display") == "block") {
```

Answer (score 1):

just a small change

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#test').css("display") === "block") {
            $('#test').css("display","none");
        } else {
            $('#test').css("display","block"); 
        }
    });            
});
```

although using jQuery toggle() function will save you some time.